# Changing numbers of references

Tags: bibliographies

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\item [\ding{45}] Accepted papers:
\bibitem{a1}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\bibitem{a2}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\bibitem{a3}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\bibitem{a4}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\item [\ding{45}] Sumitted papers:
\bibitem{c1}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\bibitem{c2}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\bibitem{c3}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\bibitem{c4}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

> I want to change the numbers of my references as follows

[image: nnnn]

Comment: But then how would the reader know the difference between you citing [1] and citing [1]?

Comment: the first one is for accepted papers and the second `1` is the first submitted references. This is for my CV.

Comment: Yeah, but referring to either using `\cite` will just output [1], which is not helpful. Or do you _just_ want to list them, without ever citing them?

Comment: Yes only the list without any citing. Just the list of my work in my cv

Comment: Ok, in that case, I will write an answer. Could you make your code example an MWE first, though? (That is, remove all unnecessary options and packages.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm sorry because I'm not an expect in Latex and I have added in my question the code of my file.

Comment: Not being an expert is okay. However, you should always provide an MWE rather than an incomplete example or your entire document, as this will help others and make answering your question easier (thus getting you more and better answers). [Here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) is some guidance on how to make a good MWE. I edited your code to be one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use a customized `ennumerate` for your list of publications or you can stick with the current `bibitem`s  and reset the corresponding counter using `\setcounter{enumiv}{0}` as shown in the following example. I have also removed code that is not directly related to the problem itself.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{sectsty}

    \frenchspacing
    \sectionfont{%
      \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
      \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
    }
\renewcommand{\refname}{Research papers}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
%--------------------

%%%%%%%%Publications%%%%%%
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\item [\ding{45}] Accepted papers:
\bibitem{a1}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\bibitem{a2}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\bibitem{a3}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\bibitem{a4}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\setcounter{enumiv}{0}
\item [\ding{45}] Sumitted papers:
\bibitem{c1}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\bibitem{c2}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\bibitem{c3}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\bibitem{c4}{xxxxxx,} xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do *not* recommend doing this, as it can only lead to confusion. If you really want to, you can reset the appropriate counter by saying

```latex
\makeatletter\setcounter{\@listctr}{0}\makeatother
```

in `thebibliography` or by just having two separate bibliographies.

As you don't want to actually cite anything, however, why not just use a list? You can emulate the look of `thebibliography` using [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section*{References}
\setlist[enumerate]{
  label={[\arabic*]},
  labelindent=0pt,
  leftmargin=*,
}

\subsection*{\ding{45} Accepted Papers}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item one
  \item two
  \item three
  \item four
\end{enumerate}

\subsection*{\ding{45} Submitted Papers}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item five
  \item six
  \item seven
  \item eight
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

---

As you seem to be writing academic papers, I would suggest ditching the rather outdated BibTeX in favor of the much more powerful [`biblatex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) for bibliographies. It is a large package and the documentation may be intimidatingly long at first, but you will find many helpful questions and answers on this site.